# FastTrack Data Warehouse -E startup parameter

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse

We are running a data warehouse based on the Fast Track architecture. One of the recommendations with Fast Track is to enable the -E parameter at SQL Server startup (increases the number of extents that are allocated for each file in a filegroup).

I've just discovered that our instance does not have this option enabled. If I enable it now, how can I ensure that existing database files are created with the additional extents?

Comment: Re-read your last sentence to yourself: "existing database files are created". You can't ensure this because they've already been created! Its probably a good idea to turn this on going forwards, but if you haven't experienced any performance issues so far from not having it, you should assess if its worth the time and effort to re-create your data files.

Comment: Yes we are experiencing performance issues. How would you recommend re-creating the files? Would a restore from backup work?

Comment: What kind of performance issues?  This might be worth a separate question with a lot more detail on your server setup, version, edition, workload and the kind of performance issues you are having.  We can keep this question and it's valid about the -E startup parameter.

Comment: Yes I will consider creating a more detailed question. At the moment I am just trying to ensure that our environment adheres to the recommendations specified in this technical article - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh918452.aspx. This document specifically says "-E must be added to the start-up options"

Comment: Thanks @johnmcp, and you are correct, the original Fast Track paper does strongly recommend enabling the `-E` startup parameter.  However, (and this is what I'm trying to get at in my main reply), I would strongly recommend making an evidence-based decision; create some trials representing your workload, run them through, get a baseline, go again.  The KB also comes with strongly worded warning which I've added to the end of my answer|.

Answer (score 1):

The option only takes effect during bulk loads to tables, so you would need to re-load your data which seems a bit pointless or accept it's only relevant for new data loads.  The [KB Article](http://web.archive.org/web/20150315181509/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/329526) is fairly clear:

> The -E option must be used before the original data load because it does not affect existing data, only new allocations.

I would also say this is one of those 'Formula 1' tuning options that I would not enable unless I had already proved it had a sufficiently positive effect using a representative test of my actual business data **and** did not have a negative impact on other key workloads.  The recommendation also comes with a caveat:

> ...data warehouse applications that have a limited number of users running index or data scans.

Is this you?

NB The KB Article also ends with a strongly worded warning:

> Because the -E option may bring performance benefits only under the specific circumstances described earlier, we do not recommend that you use this option on a regular basis. Running SQL Server with the -E option set on may decrease the performance of multiuser workloads with frequent allocations because of increased CPU consumption.